# tools produce a dependency graph for ASP.NET markup controls

Tags: asp.net

Does anyone know of an easy way to explore the dependency relationships between ASCX and ASPX files?  I'm trying to unravel some circular references and 'findstr' isn't scaling.  These dependency relationships are only established by the <%@ Register %> page directive (afaik).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dependency graphs in VS 2010 Ultimate, but the current release currently supports only .NET application projects.

You can try asking about possible support in future releases in the **Visual Studio 2010 Architectural Discovery & Modeling Tools** forum at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsarch/threads.

I know the product team would love to see customer interest for this kind of support.